# External HDD not mounted at boot, but fstab seems ok

Tags: mount, boot, hard-disk, fstab, ntfs-3g

I'm on a Raspberry with DietPI distro and I cannot mount a NTFS hard drive at boot.

This is the fstab file:

```
#Internal Drives---------------------------------------------------
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,noatime  0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
tmpfs                   /tmp                    tmpfs   noatime,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777  0 0
tmpfs                   /var/log                tmpfs   defaults,size=20m,noatime,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777  0 0
tmpfs                   /DietPi                tmpfs   defaults,size=10m,noatime,nodev,nosuid,mode=1777  0 0
UID=4E1AEA7B1AEA6007 /mnt/hdd ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0
```

The last line is the drive I want to mount at boot (the UID is correct).
The strange thing is that if I manually run `mount -a` or `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd` it works and I can see the contents of the drive in the `/mnt/hdd` directory.

Also, this is `dmesg | tail`

```
~# dmesg | tail
[    9.507925] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    9.519623] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[    9.520422] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    9.532854] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    9.616554] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    9.620081]  sda: sda1
[    9.638842] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   10.968120] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   12.556564] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
[   22.488053] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
```

UPDATE: strange output if I just run `mount`: /dev/sda1 is not listed!

```
/dev/root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=469756k,nr_inodes=117439,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=94812k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=189620k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=20480k)
tmpfs on /DietPi type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=10240k)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

UPDATE 2: this is `blkid`:

```
~# blkid 
/dev/mmcblk0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="PISD" UUID="CB99-4C7E" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="1263ae8d-aaf3-41b6-9ac0-03e7fecb5d6a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PileOfPi" UUID="4E1AEA7B1AEA6007" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Is there an error somewhere?

Comment: `UID=` should be `UUID=`. ntfs is implemented by fuse, a filesystem in user space, so "fusectl" is your mount entry.

Comment: Ok, I've corrected the UUID but nothing changes...

Comment: You dont seem to have a uuid. Perhaps it's a label? A uuid is very big, eg: UUID=37ba7eff-bc54-5d44-912e-89f3a96d8793. Try `sudo blkid` to list them.

Comment: UUID can be like mine too, in fact `blkid` shows:
`/dev/sda1: LABEL="PileOfPi" UUID="4E1AEA7B1AEA6007" TYPE="ntfs"`
Anyway I tried to replace `UUID=...` with simply `/dev/sda1`, nothing changes.

Comment: Does the mountpoint exist?

Comment: Yes @nephente, because `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd` works.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. New idea: The option `defaults` implies `auto`, which means the resource is automatically mounted at boot and with `mount -a`. Actually `mount -a` mounts everything _except_ entries with `noauto`. Try to  add `auto` or even `defaults` to the mount options in `fstab`.

Comment: The options are now `defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007` but, again, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can occur if your USB HDD is not fully powered up, before the filesystem mounting service (fstab) is completed.

[Resolution: Add a boot delay to cmdline.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=692333#p692333)

[The default /etc/fstab used in DietPi](https://github.com/Fourdee/DietPi/blob/master/dietpi/conf/fstab#L12-L13) will automatically mount a single connected ext4/ntfs drive from /dev/sda1 to /mnt/usb_1. 
Modifying the fstab entry to UUID is not required, unless you plan to have more than 1 USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

**TIP The quick reset power on power off then power back on again trick** works on almost any computer.  The second power on finds the device ready!  Why?

Both the BIOS and the Dietpi (that is FAST) are so blindingly fast that the power on does not give the peripherals like SATA HDD or USB devices time to warm up and charge their capacitors or internal CPUs and boot their own internals and they are **not ready.**

**RASPBERRY PI 6th ROW RESET PINS**

On a raspberry pi specifically buy a reset switch button that sits on 2 pins on the 6th row of the GPIO 40 pin header. PLEASE DOUBLE CHECK as this reset pins may differ according to the type of PI.  Ordinary motherboards use the same idea.  Their is however a difference between resent and power on.

(Search engine text: **Combined Restart / Shutdown Button for Raspberry Pi** )